# In dist files, why a normal -apparently- expected semicolon raises a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;" error?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I am creating a newsletter subscription API with node.js and typescript. And I'm using typeorm and PostgreSQL for the first time. Where I configured typeorm and built the entity types as described in multiple tutorials I found.

Yet I keep getting the following error for the semicolon after all the columns/attributes in each entity.

To my surprise, the error traces back to the build js code in the *dist* folder, not the source typescript code.

Error Log

```
(node:14564) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FILEPATH\fatura-backend-newsletter\dist\entity\BaseEntityAttributes.js:12
    createdAt;
             ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at C:\Users\Seif_A\Desktop\Fatura hackathon\fatura-backend-newsletter\node_modules\typeorm\util\DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:42:39
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.importClassesFromDirectories (C:\Users\Seif_A\Desktop\Fatura hackathon\fatura-backend-newsletter\node_modules\typeorm\util\DirectoryExportedClassesLoader.js:42:10)
(node:14564) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:14564) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

ormconfig.json

```
{
  "name": "mainConnect",
  "type": "postgres",
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": "5432",
  "username": "****",
  "password": "****",
  "database": "NewsletterDB",
  "synchronize": true,
  "logging": false,
  "entities": [
    "./dist/entity/*.js"
  ],
  "migrations": [
    "./dist/migration/*.js"
  ],
  "subscribers": [
    "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "cli": {
    "entitiesDir": "src/entity", "migrationsDir": "src/migration"
  }
}
```

src/entity/BaseEntityAttributes.ts

```
import { BaseEntity, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from "typeorm";

export abstract class BaseEntityAttributes extends BaseEntity {
  @CreateDateColumn({
    name: "created_at",
    type: "datetime",
  })
  public createdAt!: number;

  @UpdateDateColumn({
    name: "updated_at",
    type: "datetime",
  })
  public updatedAt!: number;
}
```

dist\entity\BaseEntityAttributes.js

```
"use strict";
var __decorate = (this && this.__decorate) || function (decorators, target, key, desc) {
    var c = arguments.length, r = c < 3 ? target : desc === null ? desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key) : desc, d;
    if (typeof Reflect === "object" && typeof Reflect.decorate === "function") r = Reflect.decorate(decorators, target, key, desc);
    else for (var i = decorators.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (d = decorators[i]) r = (c < 3 ? d(r) : c > 3 ? d(target, key, r) : d(target, key)) || r;
    return c > 3 && r && Object.defineProperty(target, key, r), r;
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.BaseEntityAttributes = void 0;
const typeorm_1 = require("typeorm");
class BaseEntityAttributes extends typeorm_1.BaseEntity {
    createdAt; // <<< Error here
    updatedAt; // <<< Also here
}
__decorate([
    typeorm_1.CreateDateColumn({
        name: "created_at",
        type: "datetime",
    })
], BaseEntityAttributes.prototype, "createdAt", void 0);
__decorate([
    typeorm_1.UpdateDateColumn({
        name: "updated_at",
        type: "datetime",
    })
], BaseEntityAttributes.prototype, "updatedAt", void 0);
exports.BaseEntityAttributes = BaseEntityAttributes;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class declaration is an ES2015 feature while public class fields

```
class X {
  publicField;
}
```

are a feature for a later ES version. If your Node version is earlier than 12, this syntax will be considered a syntax error.

Try downgrading the target ES version (ES6 or ES2015 if you aren't sure).

Comment: Thank you. Indeed I forgot I was already using nvm with node v 10.22. now I switched to v 15.9. along with some other changes and the error got away. I guess your answer is a big part of the solution.

Comment: Glad that the solution worked! But if you are using the project for production, consider a LTS version of Node (should be 14 for now).

Comment: Yes of cousre. This is just a practice project to play around and learn new tools